# start activity when custom listview button clicked

Tags: android, listview

i am developing a app that calls a web service and load the results to a list view. actually my list view has two buttons and one image view. i have use a custom list adapter class which is extends BaseAdapter. for now i just use Toast messages to identify the click events on the list items [ buttons and background of the list]. i want to start a new activity when i press a button in a list view..how can i do that ? i tried to call start activity method in onclick listener. but it didn't work..

here is my Adapter Class

```
public class NewsRowAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

private Context mContext;

public NewsRowAdapter (Context ctx) {
    mContext = ctx;
}


private Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
int resource;
    //String response;
    //Context context;
    //Initialize adapter
    public NewsRowAdapter(Activity act, int resource,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        super();
        this.resource=resource;
        this.data = d;
        this.activity = act;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }





@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {


    View vi = convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);

        TextView firstname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.fname);
        TextView lastname = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lname);
        TextView startTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.stime);
        TextView endTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.etime);
        TextView date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.blank);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);


        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song =data.get(position);

        firstname.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_PROP_FNAME));
        lastname.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_PROP_LNAME));
        startTime.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_STIME));
        endTime.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_ETIME));
        date.setText(song.get(MainActivity.TAG_DATE));
        //imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), img);

        Button accept = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        accept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final int x = (int) getItemId(position);
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"you clicked "+ x , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //Intent zoom=new Intent(mContext, Profile.class);
                //mContext.startActivity(zoom);
                //v.getContext().startActivity(zoom);

            }
        });

        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "view clicked: " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,Profile.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

        return vi;


}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}



@Override
public Object getItem(int possision) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return possision;
}



@Override
public long getItemId(int possision) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return possision;
}
}
```

StackTrace:

```
11-27 11:50:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(3974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
11-27 11:50:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(3974): java.lang.NullPointerException 
11-27 11:50:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(3974): at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
11-27 11:50:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(3974): at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3301)
11-27 11:50:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(3974): at com.jsonlist.jsonlist.NewsRowAdapter$2.onClick(NewsRowAdapter.java:103)
```

Comment: yes...toast message is shows perfectly

Comment: Hey can you check manifiest of you app, does this activity which you are calling have an entry there, i seriously see no issue with code ?

Comment: any errors in logcat?

Comment: yes i have given it to my manifest...but still didnt worked...

Comment: Check you logcat once, look for warnings

Comment: try changing it to Intent(NewsRowAdapter.this,Profile.class)

Comment: yes my log says that java.lang.nullpoint exeptioin occured

Comment: @user3020939 post the logcat here and indicate the line that caused NPE

Comment: I guess you have two constructor inside your adapter class, make sure you are using right one, cause while calling activity mContext is being used, thats the only point where null pointer can occur, if you use second constructor basically that variable will never be initialized.

Comment: @ Raghunandan this is my log cat:

11-27 11:50:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(3974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 11:50:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(3974): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 11:50:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(3974):  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
11-27 11:50:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(3974):  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3301)
11-27 11:50:20.812: E/AndroidRuntime(3974):  at com.jsonlist.jsonlist.NewsRowAdapter$2.onClick(NewsRowAdapter.java:103)

Comment: @user3020939 what is line 103 `NewsRowAdapter` and why do you have 2 constructors?

Comment: Try replacing Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,Profile.class); with Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(),Profile.class); in your onClick() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this instead.

```
Intent zoom=new Intent(parent.getContext(), Profile.class);   
parent.getContext().startActivity(zoom);
```

Comment: hi...again i could move to the next activity which i wanted to go according to your guidance. now im struggling with a dialog box. i have tried so many ways..since i am in a Adapter class i couldn't do it..can you suggest me a way to implement that ?

Comment: What you want to achieve with dialog box, and exactly what's is the problem.

Comment: Hi @Techfist. Why this code works and the original from Gishantha did not worked?

Answer (score 3):

change constructor

```
 public NewsRowAdapter(Context ctx, int resource,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    super();
    this.resource=resource;
    this.data = d;
    this.mContext = ctx;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

}

and delete first constructor

```
public NewsRowAdapter (Context ctx) {
mContext = ctx;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your activity is declared in AndridManifest.xml